# Assuming a is double, is 2.0*a faster than 2*a?

Tags: c++, performance

Long time ago in some book about the ancient FORTRAN I have seen the claim that using the integer constant with floating point variable is slower, as the constant needs to be converted to the floating point form first:

```
double a = ..;

double b = a*2;   // 2 -> 2.0 first
double c = a*2.0;
```

Is it still beneficial to write 2.0 rather than 2 in the modern C++? If not, probably the "integer version" should be preferred as 2.0 is longer and does not make any difference for a human reader.

I work with complex, long expressions where these ".0"s would make a difference in either performance or readability, if any applies.

Comment: What's stopping you from measuring and/or looking at compiler output? (Also Fortran isn't C++ so that anecdote doesn't seem relevant)

Comment: The constant in converted by compiler and final result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Original question:

Let's compare the assembly output.

```
double foo(double a)
{
        return a * 2;
}

double bar(double a)
{
        return a * 2.0f;   
}

double baz(double a)
{
        return a * 2.0;   
}
```

results in

```
0000000000000000 <foo>: //double x int
   0:   f2 0f 58 c0             addsd  %xmm0,%xmm0          // add with itself
   4:   c3                      retq                        // return (quad)
   5:   90                      nop                         // padding
   6:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1) // padding
   d:   00 00 00 

0000000000000010 <bar>: //double x float
  10:   f2 0f 58 c0             addsd  %xmm0,%xmm0          // add with itself
  14:   c3                      retq                        // return (quad)
  15:   90                      nop                         // padding
  16:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1) // padding
  1d:   00 00 00 

0000000000000020 <baz>: //double x double
  20:   f2 0f 58 c0             addsd  %xmm0,%xmm0          // add with itself
  24:   c3                      retq                        // return (quad)
```

As you can see, they are all equal and do not perform a multiplication at all.

Even when doing real multiplication (`a*5`), they are all equal and perform down to

```
0:  f2 0f 59 05 00 00 00    mulsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # 8 <foo+0x8>
7:  00 
8:  c3                      retq
```

## Addition:

@Goswin-Von-Brederlow remarks, that using a non constant expression will lead to different assembly. Let's test this like the one above, but with the following signature.

```
double foo(double a, int b); //int, float, double for foo/bar/baz
```

which leads to the output:

```
0000000000000000 <foo>: //double x int
   0:   66 0f ef c9             pxor   %xmm1,%xmm1  // clear xmm1
   4:   f2 0f 2a cf             cvtsi2sd %edi,%xmm1 // convert edi (second argument) to double
   8:   f2 0f 59 c1             mulsd  %xmm1,%xmm0  // mul xmm1 with xmm0
   c:   c3                      retq                // return
   d:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)       // padding

0000000000000010 <bar>: //double x float
  10:   f3 0f 5a c9             cvtss2sd %xmm1,%xmm1 // convert float to double
  14:   f2 0f 59 c1             mulsd  %xmm1,%xmm0   // mul
  18:   c3                      retq                 // return
  19:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)     // padding

0000000000000020 <baz>: //double x double
  20:   f2 0f 59 c1             mulsd  %xmm1,%xmm0   // mul directly
  24:   c3                      retq                 // return
```

Here you can see the (runtime) conversion from the types to a double, which leads of course to (runtime) overhead.

Comment: My point wasn't non-constant expressions but the possibility of operator overloading.

Comment: Ah, okay. I thought this, because all your examples were operating on a double. Sure, if you have a class/struct with operator overloading, it will matter as well.

Answer (score 4):

First to cover other answers, no `2` vs `2.0` will not cause a performance difference, this will be checked at compile time to create the correct value. However to answer the question:

> Is it still beneficial to write 2.0 rather than 2 in the modern C++?

**Absolutely.**

But it's not because of performance, but readability and bugs. Imagine the following operation:

```
double a = (2 / someOtherNumber) * someFloat;
```

What is the type of `someOtherNumber`? Because if it is an `integer` type then you are in trouble because of integer division. `2.0` or `2.0f` has the distinct advantages:

1. Tells the reader of the code exactly what you intended.
2. Avoids mistakes from integer division where you didn't intend it.

Answer (score 2):

#### No.

The following code:

```
double f1(double a) {
    double b = a*2;
    return b;
}

double f2(double a) {
    double c = a*2.0;
    return c;
}
```

... when compiled on gcc.godbolt.org with Clang, produces the following assembly:

```
f1(double): # @f1(double)
  addsd xmm0, xmm0
  ret
f2(double): # @f2(double)
  addsd xmm0, xmm0
  ret
```

You can see that both functions are perfectly identical, and the compiler even replaced the multiplication by an addition. I'd expect the same for any C++ compiler from this millenium -- trust them, they're pretty smart.

Comment: The question in that text is `Is it still beneficial to write 2.0 rather than 2 in the modern C++?`. I disagree that **No** is the answer to that question in the context of readability and avoiding unintended integer division.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I take the question as being strictly about performance, but I agree: using the right type of literal is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not faster. Why would a compiler wait until runtime to convert an integer to a floating point number, if it knew what that number was going to be? I suppose it's possible that you might convince some exceedingly pedantic compiler to do that, if you disabled optimization completely, but all the compilers I'm aware of would do that optimization as a matter of course.

Now, if you were doing `a*b` with `a` a floating point type and `b` an integer type, and neither one was a compile-time literal, on some architectures that could cause a significant performance hit (particularly if you'd calculated `b` very recently). But in the case of literals, the compiler already has your back.